# WinRM:: HTTPNegotiate::WinRMWebService Error while trying kitchen create to launch instance

Tags: chef-infra, winrm, test-kitchen

I was trying to launch windows-2012 instance using `kitchen-ec2` and `test-kitchen`. I was using the below `kitchen.yml` file for launching instance.I observe the instance to be created but it eventually leads to this error. can any one guide me on what's wrong with my kitchen.yml or it could be related to my instance connectivity.thanks

**Error**

> D      ------Exception------- D      Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed D
>   Message: Failed to complete #create action: [uninitialized constant
>   WinRM::HTTP::HttpNegotiate::WinRMWebServiceError] D      ---Nested
>   Exception--- D      Class: NameError D      Message: uninitialized
>   constant WinRM::HTTP::HttpNegotiate::WinRMWebServiceError D
>   ------Backtrace------- D      /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/winrm-1.7.2/lib/winrm/http/transport.rb:213:in
>   `winrm_decrypt' D
>
>   /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/winrm-1.7.2/lib/winrm/http/transport.rb:196:in`
>   send_request' D
>   /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/winrm-1.7.2/lib/winrm/winrm_service.rb:489:in
>   `send_message'

**kitchen.yml**

```
driver:
name: ec2  
associate_public_ip: false  
shared_credentials_profile: test_user 
aws_ssh_key_id: windows_test   
instance_type: t2.medium   
region: us-east-1  
availability_zone: us-east-1c  
subnet_id: subnet-a8989   security_group_ids:
   - "sg-3433"
   - "sg-abcdef"   
retryable_tries: 200  
retryable_sleep: 8

transport: 
name: winrm 
ssh_key: windowstest.pem
associate_public_ip: false
connection_timeout: 200
connection_retries: 10
username: Administrator

platforms:
  - name: windows-2012
    driver:
      image_id: ami-09udlj
      interface: private
      block_device_mappings:
        - device_name: /dev/sda1
          ebs:
            volume_size: 50
            delete_on_termination: true
            volume_type: gp2
            snapshot_id: snap-dlk0uere
        - device_name: /dev/xvdg
          ebs:
            volume_size: 30
            delete_on_termination: true
            volume_type: gp2
            snapshot_id: snap-0dfudf
      tags:
        Name: windows-2012
```

Comment: What version of ChefDK and Test Kitchen do you have installed?

Comment: @coderanger I have `chef Development Kit Version: 0.12.0`, `test-kitchen (1.6.0)`